# Smartphone with a charger of 6 ampere or more

Tags: smartphones

I seek a smartphone with a charger of 6 ampere or more.

The smartphone should include Android operating system.

What would you recommend as such a smartphone?

Comment: You are gonna need a thick cable for that. Smartphone fast charging is generally not running 5V, so they can do 65W without really thick cables

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you want 30+W charging speeds, since that is the speed of 5V * 6A. 6A is not possible though because of cable limitations.

From the Hardware.info Prijsvergelijker, the OnePlus Nord CE 2 Lite 128GB is cheap and charges at 33W (if at 5V, that would be 6.6A). Because of cable limitations though, it starts the charging at 5V * 0.5A, then tells the charger the voltage and amperage it supports. This is not gonna be 5V * 6.6A though, but probably more like 10V * 3.3A. Technically, this does not meet your requirements, but it's the closest I can get.

Except if you go make your own smartphone that is really thick to fit the charging cable required for 6A. Don't reccomend this strat though since it's very hard.

Comment: Some OnePlus (and thus likely Oppo too) devices used to charge at 30W with 5V 6A. The brick for that was called "Warp Charge 30" / "Warp Charge 30T".